# Why is there no **not equal** comparison in DynamoDB queries?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I try to query my table **Tinpon** with a secondary index yielding a partition-key **category** and sort-key **tinponId**. My goal is to exclude items with certain tinponIds. My first thought would be to make a negative compare:

    `keyConditionExpression = "category = :category AND tinponId != :tinponId"`

but there is only a equal **=** comparison. Then I tried serval other methods (with sadly do not exist):

    `keyConditionExpression = "category = :category NOT tinponId = :tinponId"
    keyConditionExpression = "category = :category AND tinponId <> :tinponId"
    keyConditionExpression = "category = :category AND tinponId < :tinponId AND tinponId > :tinponId"`

Following [the AWS guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html) there is no **not equal** comparisson. Why so?
And is there a way to query DynamoDB excluding a list of ids or is the only option to retrieve a whole bunch of items and filter them later manually?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The `KeyConditionExpression` doesn't allow not equals for the sort key. However, you can use the **"Not Equals i.e. <>"** in `FilterExpression`.

```
KeyConditionExpression : 'category = :category',    
FilterExpression : 'tinponId  <> :tinponIdVal',
ExpressionAttributeValues : {
    ':category' : 'somevalue',
    ':tinponIdVal' :  'somevalue'
}
```

Comment: Ok my next problem is that I have chosen **tinponId** as the primary key of my **Tinpon** table and now get the error `Filter Expression can only contain non-primary key attributes` is there another solution, or do I have to change the design of my table to use your suggested filtering method?

Comment: You have to use GSI (and potentially query GSI which has different partition key) or change the design of the main table to have different partition key.

Comment: @notionquest for this answer are you user query or scan operation.

Comment: Thank u V.Much... :)

Comment: This is not a useful answer, because you cannot apply filter expressions on the sort key.